# An SQL statement into SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I tried to incorporate the following into SSRS but failed.

```
If XXX = “A” then display “AT”

Else if XXX = “B” then display “BEE”

Else if XXX = “C” then display “CAR”

Else display “Other”
```

I tried

```
=Switch(
  Fields!XXX.Value = "A", "AT", 
  Fields!XXX.Value = "B", "BEE",
  Fields!XXX.Value = "C", "CAR", "Other")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it. For every output in the `Switch` function must be paired with a condition. Just make your last condition evaluate to `True`.

```
=Switch(
  Fields!XXX.Value = "A", "AT", 
  Fields!XXX.Value = "B", "BEE",
  Fields!XXX.Value = "C", "CAR", 
  True, "Other"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

`=iif(Fields!XXX.Value = "A", "AT", iif(Fields!XXX.Value = "B", "BEE", iif(Fields!XXX.Value = "C",  "CAR", "Other")))`

[check the parens in the expression builder]